how do I disconnect this vanity inlet water pipe

These are the water inlet pipes going to powder room vanity sink faucet.
Is it something I can push down/up with screwdriver or something similar.

there is a point where you can unscrew

These are crimp connectors on Pex pipes. After shutting off the water and draining pipes from a low fixture you would disconnect these by cutting them. Try to cut close to the connectors and at a perfect 90° perpendicular to the pipe so you can reconnect it later.
If you're just trying to replace a faucet, there should be faucet connections screwed to these hot/cold pipes somewhere above the photographed spot, Pex doesn't directly connect to faucets. This location would be a good spot to put 1/4-turn shutoff valves, you'd do the cutting procedure mentioned above and then crimp the shutoff valves in place.
If you're trying to remove/replace the vanity, you might consider destroying at least that corner of the vanity rather than cutting the pipes.

Thanks a lot for your response. Yes Im replacing this vanity. Unfortunately the pipes are directly connected to the faucet and there is no shutoff valve inbetween. Also you are correct, I plan to destroy that small part of vanity. As the vanity has a wooden back, I believe I will need to cut the pipes near the connector, remove the screws of vanity and pull it up. Then add the shutoff valves and then put the new vanity. Thanks again for help.
